# Accessing files in InternalStorage/Android/data/package_name/files?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, storage, android-storage

I have an app in which it has a unity part and an android part i.e. on a button click from android it opens a unity game and also downloads some files which are downloaded in  "internalstorage/Android/data/packagename/files/File_name".

Now I want to access that file from the android part but I am not getting the path of the Android folder. I have tried all the methods like getDataDir(),getFilesDir() everything but not able to locate the file.

When I check the file through the file manager I can see the file is there on the path.

In unity, I am using Application.persistentdatapath to store the file. I just want to know how I can access that file from the android part. And If I try to access the file from the Unity part I am able to access the file.

Comment: You can't access an app data folder from another app

Comment: Its a same app the unity app is integrated as a module.

Comment: If you print the values of `Application.persistentdatapath`, `getDataDir()` and `getFilesDir()`, what do you get?

Comment: getFilesDir() -  Log  "/data/user/0/com.xxxxxx.user.beta/files"                               getDataDirectory() - Log  "/data"                                                                                       Application.persistentdatapath - Log "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxxx.user.beta/files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found out instead of getFilesDir() and other method I should be using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() this returns the path "/storage/emulated/0 " and the rest I added manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```
getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath()
```

(in case anyone in 2021 is still looking for this)